# Bring back the OS X 10.9, Maverick, theme on 10.10, Yosemite, (UI Elements and Icons)

Tags: themes

I really hate the new OS X 10.10, Yosemite, icons and I just can't like the user interface. Is there a way to bring back the Maverick ones by patching some files.

P.S. I already did the reduce the transparency thing but still it sucks I just want the same old one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install a program called XRevert. This will change the buttons, icons, etc. Install cDock to change the dock. Use Lucida Grande as system font.

Comment: This will end my frustration forever! Thanks a million times. Couple of more times :)